# Not sure how to return a Class in java

Tags: java, class, arraylist

I have this class

```
public class Bid {
private User buyer;
private double bidValue;

public Bid(User buyer, double bidValue) {
  if(buyer == null || bidValue <1) {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}

this.buyer = buyer;
this.bidValue = bidValue;
}

public User getBuyer() {
 return buyer;
}


public double getBidValue() {
return bidValue;
}

public String toString() {
 return this.buyer + " bid £" + this.bidValue;
 }

}
```

and this class

```
import java.util.*;

public class Product {
private int productId;
private String productName;
private double reservedPrice;
private List<Bid> bids = null;

public Product(int productId, String productName, double reservedPrice) {
  this.productId = productId;
  this.productName = productName;
  this.reservedPrice = reservedPrice;
  this.bids = new ArrayList<Bid>();
}


public Bid getHighestBid() {
  double max = 0.0;
  for(Bid bidValue :bids) {
    if(bidValue.getBidValue() > max) 
    max = bidValue.getBidValue();
   }
  return null;
 }


}
```

In the getHighestBid method I am trying to determine the highest unique bid that a user has placed, however I am not quite sure how to do that as the return type has to be Bid and I keep getting that max cannot be resolved to type double. Although I do understand what that means but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Declare a bid variable out of for loop (like max) and then inside your if statement bid = bidValue (after max= bidValue.getBidValue). Then return bid.

Answer (score 1):

```
public Bid getHighestBid() {
  Bid max = null;
  for(Bid bidValue :bids) {
    if(max==null || bidValue.getBidValue() > max.getBidValue()) 
    max = bidValue;
   }
  return max;
}
```

You have to store the Bid object, not just the value, and then check against it.

Comment: Haha, just saw that

Comment: Good and simple answer, also easy to understand as he is just a beginner but you could improve it further, how? well you could avoid checking `max==null` by setting `Bid max = bids.get(0);` and simple checking `if(bidValue.getBidValue() > max.getBidValue()) ` instead of `if(max==null || bidValue.getBidValue() > max.getBidValue())`

Comment: You are right, I guess my thought process was to not confuse him and have the first value checked against itself (could change to a for loop instead, but again, I didn't want to make a lot of changes).

Comment: An actual indexed `for` is easier to understand than a `foreach` loop mainly because of the indexes, so it would've actually improved his understanding (in my opinion). Also checking the first value is actually equally confusing, so giving the most efficient answer of the two with minimal modification of the original solution is always ideal. Either way I up-voted yours because is the easiest to understand without much modification.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Bid getHighestBid() {
    double max = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
    Bid maxBid = null;
    for (Bid bid : bids) {
        double bidValue = bidValue.getBidValue();
        if (bidValue > max) {
            max = bidValue;
            maxBid = bid;
        }
     }
     return maxBid;
 }
```

Notes:

Perhaps allow for negative values, even though it is constrained in the constructor. Strictly speaking the could be all `NaN`.

```
double max = 0.0;
```

Each bid is a bid, not a bid value.

```
for(Bid bidValue :bids) {
```

Just keep hold of the max bid object as well as its value. (You could get the value each time, but looks cleaner if you don't.)

The stream version goes something like:

```
return bids.stream()
    .max(Comparator.comparingDouble(Bid::getBidValue)).orElse(null);
```

(As always, I have not so much as compiled this code).

Answer (score 0):

if you "just want to fix your code", you could use something like

```
public Bid getHighestBid() {
  double max = 0.0;
  Bid maxBid = null;
  for(Bid bid : bids) {
    if(bid.getBidValue() > max) 
    max = bid.getBidValue();
    maxBid = bid;
  }
  return maxBid;
}
```

but you should go one step further and implement the `Comparable`interface for bid:

```
public class Bid implements Comparable<Bid> {
   ...    
   int compareTo (Bid other) {
      // return -1,0 or 1 depending on comparison of bid Values of this and other
   }

}
```

then, in your `Product`class, you could

```
public Bid getHighestBid() {
  return Collection.max(bids);
}
```

this approach uses build-in functionality of comparison and sorting. and usually is more readable..

Comment: I wouldn't implement `Comparable` - it's a bit unnatural for a natural sort order and it is not consistent with any reasonable `equals`. From the API docs "It is strongly recommended (though not required) that natural orderings be consistent with equals.".